# Exporting games from Unity 5 to MacOS generate request for keystrokes not allowed

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine

I was trying to export some games that I created with old Unity versions to Mac.

I was able to successfully export 2 games created with Unity 2017.4.40. But now I try to export some games created with Unity 5.6.7, but every time that I try to export a game using that Unity version, I receive the following request from the system after launch the app.

[image: Request keystrokes]

The message is

```
"MyApp" would like to receive keystrokes from any application.
Grant access to this application in Security & Privacy preferences, located in System Preferences.
```

When I export games from Unity 2017.4.40, I didn't receive this message, The message only appears when I export a game from Unity 5.6.7.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade to Unity 2018.4.7 or higher.

Unity fixed this in Unity 2018.4.7f1, see their release notes https://unity3d.com/de/unity/whats-new/2018.4.7

> macOS: Fixes an issue with macOS Catalina that causes Unity to request
> permission to receive keyboard input when using other apps in both the
> editor and standalone player. (1172758)

Comment: It is already fixed in Unity 2017.4.40. But I can't update some apps because there significant changes in Unity Engine. Since some apps I use a template that I purchase from UnityAssetStore and it's discontinued by the developer, I use this template to create the game, part of the code is not created by me and I don't know how to change it. There is any workaround for that?

Comment: Because this change is internal C++ Unity code you would have to reach out to Unity and fix the engine yourself. Last I checked they requested pretty penny for access to the engine source code.

It will be easier for you to upgrade the template then to fix the engine itself.